# Having an issue with a NullPointer and ListView

Tags: java, android

This is the code which is causing the error. Sorry I changed so much from my original post, but I have placed all the code in one place now. Tell me if this is a terrible idea.

I get my error on the line that sets the myArrayAdapter for my ListView

```
public class DisplayCaf extends Activity implements OnNavigationListener {
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = null;
    //Holds items.
    ArrayList<String> menuArray;
    //String adapter for ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;
    //set listView
    ListView listView;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.pager_caf);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        menuArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        //set up the adapter for listView
        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuArray);
        //connect adapter to feed info to listView
        listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened with that switch? You're doing exactly the same thing in all the cases. If you just want to make sure it's between 1 and 6, wrap those 2 lines of code in a `if(position <= 0 && position <= 6)`

Comment: Post your logcat trace

Comment: Is the ListWiew 'listView' in the Layout 'pager_caf'?

Comment: Yes, my ListView is in the correct layout file ('pager_caf')

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is with the limited information you provided: the fact you have posted a lot of code, as you said, doesn't mean you have provided the right one (for instance you  pasted that big switch that probably doesn't matter, and you didn't pasted the layout...).

My best guess is that the call to

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position);
```

happens right after the call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.pager_caf);
```

and therefore the adapter never gets a chance of being initialized.

If you want to have a clearer picture of what's happening, help yourself first: place a couple of Log.d here and there (right at the start of instantiateItem and before and after setContentView might be a good start...), reduce your problem to the essential parts (bisecting it until only the bug remains) and post the code that remains (as well as the logs).

Comment: What information do you need? I'm willing to share as much as you need. This is only my second time asking a question on here, so I know my info may be a bit scant.

Comment: The logcat trace that Pragnani already mentioned above might be a good start... :) My point however is that you need to reduce the size of the code before asking for help and provide an example with just what you need to reproduce the bug. Not only this will likely get you more assistance, but odds are that while trimming the source code you'll be able to track the bug yourself.